# Calculating Slope One differentials from MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I have 3 collections in my training database-- Users, Businesses, and Reviews. I'd like to predict ratings for other items using slope one, but I'm not sure how to best collect the rating differentials from MongoDB between businesses.

I have 200,000 ratings within the Review collection, and I'd like to compare only businesses that have a shared category. So, I find all the users that have reviews for businesses under those categories.

```
business = businesses.find({'categories':{"$in" : business_categories}},{'business_id'})

for biz in all_businesses:
    biz_list.append(biz['business_id'])
reviews = training_reviews.find({'business_id':{"$in" : biz_list}})

for review in reviews:
    review_list.append(review['user_id'])

available_users = users.find({'user_id':{"$in": review_list}})
```

Once I have my users, I need to set up a matrix of all of their ratings so I can calculate the differential between each business.  My minimum size matrix is going to be 10k x 10k, and because I will have several categories for each recommendation I'm making, I'll have to redo it for each recommendation.

Is there an efficient way to do this in python? Would it be better to export a rating matrix for ALL businesses and then predict ratings from that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would say if you are looking for efficiency, you should try to get all the relevant information into embedded documents in the reviews collection.

This would mean you can aggregate in MongoDB

See [Model One-to-Many Relationships with Embedded Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) for a discussion on modelling using embedded documents as opposed to normalising 
 and the general topic [Data Models](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/)